# Nanocar racing competition and the race tracks used

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, metal, surface-chemistry, nanotechnology

In the [Nanocar race competition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanocar_Race) the molecules are raced on a gold surface. 
Is there a specific property of gold that it forms a good "racetrack"? On what criteria does it compare with other metal surfaces?

Comment: While adsorption certainly is needed, the gold might be also there for contingent reason, as imaging via AFM and sample preparation. For instance , if the substrate must be conductive, than something rather inert would be preferable to iron.  Let us wait for a more informed user.  I just point to (also) not intrinsic race related reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can't find specific justification for the surface, the first competition involved both gold and silver "racetracks."

- [Drivers gear up for world’s first nanocar race](https://doi.org/10.1038/544278a)
- [How to build and race a fast nanocar](https://doi.org/10.1038/nnano.2017.137)

The competition involves propulsion and imaging using [STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope) so the substrate must be conductive. Gold (and silver to a lesser degree) is particularly useful, since it won't [easily oxidize](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38996/why-is-gold-so-popular-in-nanotechnology?rq=1) and is easy to purify.

I've seen several comments about having 'tracks' in the gold surface, which suggests a well-defined crystal face with reconstruction, e.g. Au(100):

[image: Au(100) surface reconstruction from Wikipedia]

(Image from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Atomic_resolution_Au100.JPG))

Comment: I know a few people interested in "theoretical" nano car racing simulations, and will revise my answer as I hear back about specific reasons.